# Better way of using stim.TableauSimulator.measure_many to sample the code

Tags: stim

I have a TableauSimulator initialised (which is a some 3D code) called TS. I am copying TS and then applying a set of Pauli Z-errors before using measure_many(*set_of_measured_qubits) to get syndromes results. I am looping this many times to compute some sort of psuedo-threshold. This is currently quite slow and more than 90% of the runtime resides in the measure_many function alone. I wanted to ask if anyone knows how I can sample the Tableau simulator better if all I am doing is independent X or Z errors on the qubits?

Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`stim.Circuit.compile_sampler`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Circuit.compile_sampler) if you want a lot of samples. For example:

```
from typing import Optional

import numpy as np
import stim


def mega_sample(*,
                initial_state: Optional[stim.TableauSimulator] = None,
                end_of_circuit: stim.Circuit,
                num_shots: int) -> np.ndarray:
    if initial_state is None:
        prepare_state_circuit = stim.Circuit()
    else:
        prepare_state_circuit = initial_state.current_inverse_tableau().inverse().to_circuit(method='elimination')
    full_circuit = prepare_state_circuit + end_of_circuit

    bulk_sampler: stim.CompiledMeasurementSampler = full_circuit.compile_sampler()
    shots: np.ndarray = bulk_sampler.sample(shots=num_shots)
    return shots


def test():
    t = stim.TableauSimulator()
    t.h(0)
    t.cnot(0, 1)
    rest = stim.Circuit("""
        # noise channels
        Z_ERROR(0.1) 0 1
        
        # clifford operations transforming the noise
        H 0 1
        
        # measurements
        M 0 1
    """)
    for shot in mega_sample(initial_state=t, end_of_circuit=rest, num_shots=1024):
        print(shot)
```

The only reason you wouldn't do this is if, in between the noise and the measurements, you needed classically controlled Clifford operations (e.g. for a repeat-until-success construction).

Actually, in contexts where you only care whether or not measurements are *flipped* (such as when **correcting errors** *hint hint*), you should go even further and never touch `stim.TableauSimulator` or raw measurements at all. You should make a `stim.Circuit`, and use [`stim.Circuit.compile_detector_sampler`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Circuit.compile_detector_sampler) on it. This requires you to add `DETECTOR` annotations and `OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE` annotations to the circuit, but it completely avoids ever constructing a tableau. This avoids all quadratic simulation costs, so that everything is linear in the number of simulated gates. It's thousands of times faster.

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there anyway to output the error locations of "Z_ERROR(0.1) 0 1" within each sample? Cheers.

Comment: @QW Not with the circuit sampler. The detector error model sampler does support this, and you can use stim.Circuit.explain_errors to convert those back into these Z errors.

Comment: @QW You could also use CORRELATED_ERROR instead of Z_ERROR to have the errors flip ancilla qubits that you measure to determine which ones occurred.

Comment: Thanks, is there no way to specific the locations of the Z_ERROR before the sampler stage?

Comment: @QW you could use a sweep target and then specify sweep bits... but this is only really supported in the unstable C++ API IIRC. Also the whole thing is set up to not treat them as errors. In general I've focused on sampling rather than controlling errors which is why this is hard.